# Apache22: how to redirect a dir to https?

Tags: apache, redirect

Say, I have a domain `http://www.example.com`. I have this in *httpd.conf*: `DocumentRoot "/Apache22/htdocs"`.

I also have `/Apache22/htdocs/dir1` application directory, which I want to force users to connect to with `https`, say, with URL: `https://www.example.com/dir1` and redirect any `http` requests to `https` for this directory.

I tried *VirtualHost* and *Redirect* so:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /Apache22/htdocs/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com/dir1
DocumentRoot /Apache22/htdocs/dir1
Redirect permanent /dir1 https://www.example.com/dir1
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com/dir1
DocumentRoot /Apache22/htdocs/dir1
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl/server.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

But apparently Apache ignores any subdrectories in *ServerName*, so both *www.example.com* and *www.example.com/dir1* are the same in *VirtualHost* block, as far as Apache concerned.

How do I achieve an `https` redirect of any URL accessing *dir1*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /Apache22/htdocs/

Redirect permanent /dir1 https://www.example.com/dir1
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com

DocumentRoot /Apache22/htdocs

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl/server.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The `ServerName` directive takes a host name, not anything including a path component.